# Расширение .trc .Как правильно считать и отобразить в Open_GL?

Tags: c++, qt

Я попытался открыть это  формат, но я как понял, он закодировал либо сильно ужат.
Данные ("qqqq.trc") взяты  с осциллографа. Как это отобразить, хотя бы для начала прочитать ума не приложу.

```
  QString str;
  char ch;
  //QFile file ("qqqq.txt");
  QFile file ("qqqq.trc");
  file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
  for (;!file.atEnd();)
  {
      file.getChar(&ch);
      str += ch;
      //qDebug() <<str;
  }
  qDebug() <<str;
```

Все что он мне выдает это

```
  "rc8
```

В интернете пытался разузнать про расширение .trc ни чего не нашёл, а что нашёл то не понял. Связку .trc С++, .trc Qt, тоже искал.

Comment: Попробуйте открыть файл в бинарном формате. И почитайте мануал к вашему осциллографу-источнику.

Comment: Вот есть на питоне проект https://github.com/yetifrisstlama/readTrc

Comment: Наверно только вручную разбирать, вот описание формата http://forums.ni.com/attachments/ni/60/4652/2/LeCroyWaveformTemplate_2_3.pdf