# Как на питоне открывать .trc файлы?

Tags: python, ide

В общем пытаюсь прочитать фаил .trc . решил воспользоваться ответом из вопроса 
[Расширение .trc .Как правильно считать и отобразить в Open_GL?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/512040/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-trc-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-open-gl?noredirect=1#comment623427_512040)

"Вот есть на питоне проект github.com/yetifrisstlama/readTrc – Cerbo 13 апр в 6:21"

Но при запуске он мне жалуется и выдает ошибку :

```
   UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 18: ordinal not in range(128)
```

.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""  # -*- coding: cp1251 -*-
Little helper function to load data from a .trc binary file.
This is the file format used by LeCroy oscilloscopes.
M. Betz 09/2015
"""

#form __fiture__ import with_statement #для питон 2.5
import datetime
import numpy as np
import struct
print 1


fName = "Newfile1a.trc";

with open(fName, "rb") as fid:
    #data = fid.read(50).encode() 
    data = fid.read(50).decode()
    wdOffset = data.find('WAVEDESC')
    print 2
```

П.С. Spyder (IDE) очень хороша , есть ли такая же хрень тока на Qt 4.8 ?????

Comment: Попробуйте в `decode` указать кодировку вашего файла. И выкладывайте всегда полный стек, а не только само сообщение ошибки -- чуть не предложил в open добавить атрибут encoding, пока не заметил, что режим `rb`

Comment: Я не знаю в какой кодировке .trc файлы укладывают .  Единственное чтоя знаю что  это (формат) баз данных , в котором в начале  заголовок файла идет. Там явно используются переменные разного формата. От байта до дабла. И после прочтения заголовка раскрывается механизм считывания основной информации . НО у меня проблема в самом начале ;_; .

Comment: Чтобы узнать какой формат, можно открыть, например Notepad++ и посмотреть. Или в коде указывайте в `decode()` указывайте разные кодировки, пока ошибка не пропадет. Попробуйте с utf-8 или latin1

Answer (score 1):

Тут одно из двух: либо ваш файл не соответствует стандарту, либо вам посоветовали плохой парсер.

Из описания `.trc` формата:

> <  0>          DESCRIPTOR_NAME: string  ; ***the first 8 chars are always WAVEDESC***
>
> < 16>          TEMPLATE_NAME: string
>
> < 32>          COMM_TYPE: enum          ; chosen by remote command COMM_FORMAT

а утилита пытается прочитать сразу 50 байт и декодировать их:

```
data = fid.read(50).decode()
wdOffset = data.find('WAVEDESC')
```

В этом формате, тип `string` описывается как:

> string - up to 16-character name terminated with a null byte

т.е. судя по всему, это тип с фиксированным размером (в байтах).

Могу посоветовать подправить утилиту и сделать так, чтобы она читала не 50 байт, а только 16 (или даже 8):

```
data = fid.read(16).decode()
```

остальную логику это никак не должно сломать.

И да, по заверениям автора утилиты, она тестировалась на Python 3, поэтому и вам стоит использовать именно третью версию, пока не взлетит. А потом уже можно будет пробовать запустить и на 2.6.